# extract 32bit from 64bit integer

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion

I have an `uint64_t`  integral number and extracted the last 32bit into a `uint32_t` number by the following code:

```
uint32_t getLast(uint64_t v){
      uint64_t t= v >> 32;
      return  reinterpret_cast<uint32_t &>( t ); // type-punned pointer warning
}

int main()
{
    uint64_t a = 1l << 33 | 1l << 3;
    std::cout << getLast(a) << std::endl; // prints 2
}
```

This code gives the warning:

```
warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       return  reinterpret_cast<uint32_t &>( t );
```

I want to fix this, but not by using a union type.

The `reinterprete_cast` gives undefined behaviour, when accessing the data (copying the reinterpreted stuff into the return value) (i think?)

Another solution which seems to work?

```
 uint32_t getLast(uint64_t v){

    return (v >> 32) // conversion from bitshifted 64bit to 32bit, but what is with overflow?
 }
```

I am bit confused, about the undefined behaviour of reinterpret_cast?
So how should I use `reinterpret_cast`, i thought that this example is the archi-typical usage pattern? Will the second method work safely too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should just `static_cast<uint32_t>`. `reinterpret_cast` is pretty much exclusively used for highly dodgy and probably illegal pointer casting.

Comment: so static_cast 64bit ignores the last 32bits?

Comment: Yep. The Standard behaviour is truncation. Beware that signed and unsigned behave very differently...